# flutter where should I put firestore timestamp setting on Android

Tags: android, flutter

When using `firestore` console message saying you need to write timestamp setting.
On iOS I wrote in `appdelegete` and no message anymore but I'm from iOS land so I'm not sure where I should put those on Android side.
Where should I put those?

**Console message**

```
Firestore(25948):
W/Firestore(25948): FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
W/Firestore(25948): FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
W/Firestore(25948):     .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
W/Firestore(25948):     .build();
W/Firestore(25948): firestore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve this with Dart code:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await Firestore.instance.settings(
    timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: true,
  );

  runApp(...);
}
```

Comment: Don't I have to write this on native side? Have you tried this and worked?

Comment: Of course, this should be anyway added to the Dart code, because otherwise you have to add dependencie (to native) which already comes from the plugin (cloud_firestore)

Comment: The parameter timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled is not available anymore, anybody knows why?

Comment: @JoanP.S: you might have found it already because I am very late to the party, but here is a link: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2259#issuecomment-655446116

it was removed because it's default behavior now.